# VBA set Text file to read/write and then back to read only?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following vba code to write to a text file.

```
'Create log file
Dim FF
FF = FreeFile()
Open "G:\WH DISPO\(3) PROMOTIONS\(18) L.O. Delivery Tracking\Reports\LogFile.txt" For Append As #FF
Print #FF, Now() & " - " & Application.UserName & " accessed the Delivery Tracker."
Close #FF
```

I want to toggle the text file from read only to read/write access and then back to read only once the code has completed.

Ideally i would like to try and prevent a user being able to change the read/write permissions of this file manually also, by setting a password to protect the log file.

But i'm not sure if this is possible.

Please can someone show me how to do get this code to do what i need? Thanks in advance

Comment: I you need to control access to your log with a password, you might want to consider logging to a database or another Excel file instead of a text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are looking for the `SetAttr` function in Excel. The following code should do the trick:

```
Dim FF
FF = FreeFile()
SetAttr "G:\WH DISPO\(3) PROMOTIONS\(18) L.O. Delivery Tracking\Reports\LogFile.txt", vbNormal
Open "G:\WH DISPO\(3) PROMOTIONS\(18) L.O. Delivery Tracking\Reports\LogFile.txt" For Append As #FF
Print #FF, Now() & " - " & Application.UserName & " accessed the Delivery Tracker."
Close #FF
SetAttr "G:\WH DISPO\(3) PROMOTIONS\(18) L.O. Delivery Tracking\Reports\LogFile.txt", vbReadOnly
```

For more information you might want to read the following on MSDN:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a5wx7516(v=vs.90).aspx